# ActualHeight and ActualWidth of object is always zero

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, actualwidth, actualheight

I have a `Canvas` with a `TextBlock` like so:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" DoubleTapped="ContentPanel_DoubleTapped">
        <TextBlock x:Name="WordBlock" FontSize="226.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" TextAlignment="Center"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
```

My app is such that when the user navigates to this page, the `TextBlock` will be centered in the `Canvas` and if the `TextBlock`'s width is greater than that of the canvas, the marquee animation will occur:

```
private void SetAnimation()
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(WordBlock, (ContentPanel.ActualWidth - WordBlock.ActualWidth) / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(WordBlock, (ContentPanel.ActualHeight - WordBlock.ActualHeight) / 2);

    if (WordBlock.ActualWidth > ContentPanel.ActualWidth)
    {
        MarqueeAnimation.From = WordBlock.ActualWidth;
        MarqueeAnimation.To = -WordBlock.ActualWidth;
        MarqueeAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
        MarqueeBoard.Begin();
    }
}
```

This method is called OnNavigatedTo. I can't figure out why the `TextBlock` won't center because the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties are always coming back as 0.0. I don't want to put fixed sizes because this is a Windows Store app and would like for it to be scalable across different screen sizes.

Any ideas? I'm stuck.

Comment: How are you setting the text for WordBlock?

Comment: On the previous page, passing the content of a TextBox as a navigation parameter, then retrieving it from OnNavigatedTo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When OnNavigatedTo is called I don't believe the page has actually been drawn yet.  I had similar confusion when trying to resize and rearrange things.  The answer appeared to be to wait until the page has loaded and do the calculation then:

```
public ChallengePage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.Loaded += ChallengePage_Loaded;
}

void ChallengePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  *Do your calculations which use ActualWidth and ActualHeight in here*
}
```

You'll need something like that I believe.  Adding the Loaded handler into your initialize for the page, and then you can call SetAnimation from in there.

Comment: So I'll use OnNavigatedTo to retrieve the word that I'm passing to this page and set it as the value of WordBlock, then resize and rearrange everything on Loaded?

Comment: Yes, make the change to the text when you navigate, let the page load so that it's actually rendered the objects, and then they should have sizes so that you can rearrange in loaded :o)